# MySQL does not match desired records while doing match between integer and varchar ID

Tags: mysql, join, integer, left-join, varchar

I am doing a query, ie:

```
SELECT
    `Transaction`.`id`,
    `Transaction`.`total`,
    `Transaction`.`customer_id`,
    `Customer`.`id`,
    `Customer`.`full_name`
FROM
    `mydb`.`transactions` AS `Transaction`
LEFT JOIN `mydb`.`users` AS `Customer` ON (
    `Transaction`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`
)
WHERE
    `Transaction`.`customer_id` = '573edc-fa84-44a2-9bce-0d650ab724ab'
LIMIT 1
```

Look at the result (which is incorrect) below:

[image]

In the Transactions table the "customer_id" fields is a varchar(255) field while in "users" table id field is an integer(11) field. I need to keep customer_id field varchar as it is supposed to store a 36 characters long random string for guest users. Here in this query it is treating customer_id as Integer and hence truncates everything after the integer value and matches it with actual user ID 573.

When I do a join like this this it matches a record which has User ID 573. I am not sure what I should do in order to match records correctly. In this case there should have not record in users table actually, as it a transaction done by guest user without login.

What is the work around here? I am not going to change user id field to varchar or customer_id to integer but still want to do the correct match.

I am working on CakePHP but it does not matter I think as it gives me same result when I run it directly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Well of course it ****** doesn't.

Comment: Is there any workaround at all?? 

Thank you for vote down anyways!!

Comment: A workaround for what? Store corresponding keys using the same data type.

Comment: I can't. It is a quite large system having dozens of websites using the same structure and sharing the code with individual databases. But I need a fix which could fix this bug in all websites at once. The customer id and user ID are being used at several places so there is no way to replace them.

Comment: There's no bug here. Just a deeply flawed design on the part of the dba.

Comment: I am looking for a fix here. Not want to learn the design and structures here right now. I am good enough with that I think.

Comment: What should the 'fix' do, exactly?

Comment: I will surely post it here for you guys whenever I find it. :)

Comment: There is no user with the corresponding id, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: Yes I dont want anything in the users section and want them null when there is no user. But it is matching 573 which I dont want.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit integer conversion of transaction.customer_id in the on statement, since the conversion only looks at the numeric portion the conversion results in a value of 573 hence you get a match with users.customer_id. You need to convert or cast the users.customer_id to char in your join statement.

Comment: Yes it looks like an answer. Working on this. Thanks!